# OpenGL ES 2.0 VBO issue

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I am trying to switch to VBOs, without indices for now. But all I get is just a blank screen. Can someone point out why it is blank? The same code works fine if I comment out the vbo-specific code and replace 0(offset) in glVertexAttribPointer by mFVertexBuffer, i.e without using VBOs.

This is my onDraw method

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.50f, 0.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
// Bind default FBO
//    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
checkGlError("glUseProgram");



GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
int vertexCount = mCarVerticesData.length / 3;

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
checkGlError("1");
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false, 0, 0);
checkGlError("2");
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
checkGlError("3 ");
transferTexturePoints(getTextureHandle());
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

This is my vbo setup:

```
// Allocate and handle vertex buffer
    ByteBuffer vbb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mCarVerticesData.length
            * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES);
    vbb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb2.asFloatBuffer();
    mFVertexBuffer.put(mCarVerticesData);
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);

    // Allocate and handle vertex buffer

    this.buffers = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mFVertexBuffer.capacity()
            * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES, mFVertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Before linking my program:

```
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "aPosition");
checkGlError("bindAttribLoc");
```

And my vertex shader is :

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoordinate;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinate;
void main() 
{
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
  v_TextureCoordinate = aTextureCoordinate;
  gl_PointSize=  10.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by rewriting the way I was uploading vertices data. I was modifying it and so, I needed to call glBindBufferData again for it to be uploaded. And I was able to use VBOs without using glDrawElements and indices, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also generate an elements array and call something like this in order to render your "object":

```
// Bind the vertex buffer 
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferIds.get(2));
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4*4, 0);
// Bind the elements buffer and draw it
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bufferIds.get(1));
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, _numElements, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But wouldn't that be only for glDrawElements with indices?

EDIT: I'm trying to draw a lot of points which I might change every frame. In such a setup, Indices would be unnecessary (please correct me if I'm wrong)! Now, I'm trying to use a VBO just to see how it behaves with a 'stream' input.

Comment: You are incorrect, you need indice. Indices are that, something opengl uses to address which points should be drawn (in your case is easy, just a linear array of indices starting at 0 and ending at max_points-1). Without indices, nothing will not show up on your screen.

Comment: I tried including indices in my code but still I couldn't get it to work. getGLError returns 0, so no error there. If I try including some code without VBO, it displays the non-VBO objects fine.

Also, googling does tell me that indices are only required for Indexed rendering, which I do not require as I don't have multiple objects which share vertices. My application displays mostly point sprites.

Comment: Also, would VBOs be faster than client-side arrays to display point sprites, whose positions are updated each frame? I am using the STREAM hint, as I want to test the performance difference between updating client-side arrays each frame vs updating the VBO, and then settle on the better method. The positions are fetched from another thread, and cannot be calculated on the vertex shader.

Comment: My VBO setup and drawing is similar to this. I am using glDrawArrays, like in the link, instead of glDrawElements as @TraxNet as mentioned.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object